# how to query from realm database with distinct results java

Tags: java, android, realm, nosql

I have got a `Realm` object class, and storing lots of data in there, imagine that I have a  `String uid;`  field. I want to get uid names, but on same uid names just only one time, 
For example

### uid

AA

AA

BB

CC

DD

BB

BB

I want to get just
 AA,

BB,

CC,

DD.

Only one time.
I looked over realm documentation but couldn't find anything.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: @MD hi, thanks for answer, but the realm is no-sql database. how can we do this?

Comment: I don't see any direct capability to do this. Perhaps, you'll need to add your query results iteratively to a `Set` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**UPDATED :**

You can use distinct() to get distinct entries for an object class.

```
// Returns the set of users that all have a different name
RealmResults<User> users = realm.where(User.class).distinct("name");
```

Note:
 .distinct will only work on fields that are indexed (@Index or @PrimaryKey).
It doesn't work with child object property.

You can find more information about this method here in the official documentation.
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#distinct-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-][1]

Comment: realm.distinct is not working in Realm 1.1.0 android version how it will work please help me

Comment: @pradeepbishnoi Updated my answer. Please check.They have changed it you can see the list of changes in their change log [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: What if want to know the number of items that we ignored?

Comment: distinct is not showing the updated db values.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below steps to work distinct on Realm

Update your realm version to realm :1.2.0 . because in older version distinct not working properly.

add @Index property to variable on which you want to apply distinct

execute your query like this

```
RealmResult<Example> realmReault =realm.where(Example.class).distinct("uid");
```

to include realm dependency in your project you can add below line in build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Above code is tested and working properly

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are almost correct, but still incomplete.

The other solutions need to use `.findAll()` so that the return value remain RealmResult type.

```
RealmResult<Example> realmReault =realm.where(Example.class).distinct("uid").findAll();
```

On realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2,