# Duplicate remove distinct does not work on Android Realm

Tags: android, realm

[image]

Hello, I want to get `nal` is `2018-03-23` and `inout` is `I` Data.

in picture, result size is 7.

but I want when I get the result size, after duplicate remove the cardnum.

finally, reuslt size must be 2.

my source

```
RealmQuery<InOutDB> resInEmp;
long resultIn;

Realm realm;

public void getSize() {
  realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
  realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
     @Override
     public void execute(Realm realm) {
        resInEmp = realm.where(InOutDB.class).equalTo("nal", "2018-08-23").equalTo("inout", "I").distinct("cardnum"); // value 7

        resultIn = resInEmp.count(); //value 7
     }
  });
}
```

how to use distinct on Android realm?

thanks.

Comment: Please read this carefully. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35132251/3713967

Comment: @SameerDonga I try link answer. but  result size 7.

Comment: have you read this "Note: .distinct will only work on fields that are indexed (@Index or @PrimaryKey). It doesn't work with child object property."

Comment: @SameerDonga oh.. sorry, I was too hasty. thanks.

Comment: Not to mention, `distinct` is part of the query now. What version of Realm is this? It looks older than 4.0.0?

Comment: oh right, I think I remember a bug regarding `distinct()` mixed with `count()`, and it would work if you do `distinct().findAll().size()` instead.